# J2me Createplayer does not work on samsung phones

Tags: java-me, samsung-mobile, mmapi

I am trying to create J2me application which will capture the image and upload it on the server.

I have used following code for capture image.

```
 player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
 player.realize();
 videoControl = (VideoControl) (player.getControl("VideoControl"));
```

The above code does work on all Nokia phones,  it does not show camera to capture image neither it give any exception in Samsung phones.

Please direct me to links where the capture image code works for Samsung java enabled phones.

Comment: does your samsung device has camera ? which model you are using ?

Comment: yes my phone has camera model name is Samsung Champ Deluex Deous.

Comment: Your Phone is [Java](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_c3312_duos-4403.php) Supported, but no detail about MIDP.

Comment: Yes my phone is java Supported IT uses  MIDP 2.0

Answer (score 1):

I've been through the same situation. You need to *add a call to player.start()*.

In my case I did it **after** obtaining and adjusting the videoControl.

Comment: Thanks Telmo , i will try to do the same. But i have checked the the property called Supports.Video.Capture it returning false does it mean my phone does not support the image capture facility.

Comment: Yes, when supports.video.capture returns false video capture is not supported. As found in http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/mmapioptions/